# Can't route pages in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

## I want to using the **BrowserRouter** component from the react-router-dom library to handle client-side routing in React.Js

In this case, when the user navigates to the every URL of the website, these pages component will be rendered. But nothing shows up to the root directory or any path.

Here is the code of **app.js**

```
import React from "react";
import GlobalStyle from "./globalStyle.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

//Pages
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import Pricing from "./Pages/PricingPage.js";
import Signup from "./Pages/SignupPage.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <GlobalStyle />
      Test
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/pricing" component={Pricing} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `react-router-dom` v6, the routes should be:

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
<Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
<Route path="/pricing" element={<Pricing />} />
```

`component` is `element`, their values are in tags.